# How to add stylecop check as a pre-build action to VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-automation, stylecop

In our project we have added StyleCop task to be executed after each commit by continuous integration server. The problem is that build often breaks because someone forgets to run Stylecop before commiting code to repository.

The solution will be to execute StyleCop before each VS2010 build. How can I do it?
Maybe it is possible to execute pre-build action per whole solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you could use MSBuild integration (look [here](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setting%20Up%20StyleCop%20MSBuild%20Integration&referringTitle=Documentation) or [here](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Running%20StyleCop%20in%20VS2005%20or%20VS%20Express&referringTitle=Documentation)), which will make StyleCop checking a part of a build process.

Or you could use some sort of "commit policies" which run StyleCop during the commit and reject the commit if StyleCop checking is not passed. For example, [here](http://sourceanalysispolicy.codeplex.com/) is one for TFS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We already have msbuild integration in our daily build on CC.Net. What I would like add it's VS2010 integration before each project build.

Comment: "Team Development" paragrgaph in the first link describes how to update your porject file (<Import Project="$(StyleCopTargets)" />) in order VS2010 to run StyleCop every time when VS2010 builds your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are SyleCop rule for all project in local or your teams ?
**Hook MSBuild script** !!

1. Make folder in %ProgramFiles%\MSBuild\v4.0 
   v4.0 folder name is your .net framework. 
   ie. 
   v3.5 for .net framework 3.5
   v4.0 for between 4.0 and 4.5...
2. then make "Custom.After.Microsoft.Common.targets" and "Custom.Before.Microsoft.Common.targets"
   my experience was "Custom.Before.Microsoft.Common.targets" was not working well.
3. In "Custom.After.Microsoft.Common.targets" file contained under code
   then StyleCop analysis before CoreCompile

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`

```
<PropertyGroup>

    <CI_StyleCopPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\StyleCop\v4.7</CI_StyleCopPath>

    <StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="$(CI_StyleCopPath)\StyleCop.targets"
        Condition=" Exists('$(CI_StyleCopPath)\StyleCop.targets') "/>

<!-- Analysis with StyleCop before build -->
<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
        StyleCop;       <!-- StyleCop.targets       -->
        $(BuildDependsOn);
    </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

`</Project>`

See my blog but contents are Korean ;-) 
http://xyz37.blog.me/50053407359